# Saving the data in a Visualforce page when an object is saved

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

I'm using Salesforce Classic.  I've created a custom object called `Proposal`.  The object is displayed using a page layout.  Within the layout I want to include a custom Visualforce page.  The Visualforce page will include a couple of fields that involve complex lookups that I can't achieve using a Lookup field type.  I would like saved back to the `Proposal` object when the user clicks the [Save] button for the object.  How do I save the fields in the Visualforce page at the same time the `Proposal` object is saved?

Comment: You can view the Save button when you're on the Edit page layout. Unfortunately, visualforce page cannot be displayed on the Edit page layout in Salesforce classic. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br8CAAS  Why don't you add a Save button to the visualforce?

Comment: Then the user would need to click the [Save] button in the visualforce page to save that change, then click the [Save] button in the object to save any changes there.

Comment: Yes, as you say or vice versa. Because the standard Save button in the object page layout cannot execute any action in the visualforce.

Comment: I agree the User Experience is not super intuitive but why not create a save button on the VF Page (doesnt have to be named "save" maybe "update ... info" is better) and then either: 
Save and redirect to the Proposal or 
Save and use Javascript to display the updated info in the vf page


That way either way if you click on save (or update), the new lookups ( and possible dependent information) is saved and presented to the user.